# Difference between vector and Derived vector class

Tags: c++, vector

What is difference between:

```
class Derived : public std::vector<Base> {};
```

and

```
std::vector<Base> Derived;
```

?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between a blueprint and a building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, `Derived` is a class which can be used to declare a variable.  In the second `Derived` is a variable name of type `std::vector<Base>`.

In the case of the class it is possible to produce undefined behaviour with the following code:

```
void deleter(std::vector<Base>* ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
}


void buggy()
{
    auto ptr = new Derived();
    // ... operations on ptr.
    deleter(ptr);   // Oops.
}
```

The problem is that `std::vector` doesn't have a virtual destructor, so the
deletion is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Its completely two different things. when you derive a new class you can add functionality and change behaviour. 
If you leave the derived class empty the result is the same but it still better if you want to change it in the future

Comment: Well, if you leave derived class empty - they aren't the same thing, since you can't call the constructors of Base class through the Derived class instance.